# Merge Hydrography and Hydrology into Hydro

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

I never really understood what separates [hydrology](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrology) from [hydrography](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrography) (maybe same as what separates [geology](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geology) from [geography](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography)?)

Anyway, I think others have dealt with the issue by just calling both of them it hydro when it relates to GIS.  Should we merge [hydrology](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrology) and [hydrography](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydrography) into [hydro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hydro)?

Answer (score 3):

Kirk people involved in the disciplines would argue otherwise.... 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrography,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrology
as one could see from generic content.  Being a Geographer, I can assure you that it is quite different than Geology and I would prefer not to open a debate on the similarities, but would not that some Geographers are interested in Post-Modernism and Globalisation whereby I would venture that Geologists are not :)

Comment: +1 I just checked: arguably every one of the questions tagged "hydrography" should read "hydrology".  I don't recall ever seeing a real hydrography question on this site (although I have, from time to time, on other sites and lists).  We have seen lots of hydrology, some bathymetry, and a tiny bit of oceanography questions.

Comment: So if the hydrography tag is being misused maybe it should be removed or collapsed into a general hydrog tag, per Kirk's suggestion.

Comment: I was thinking in context of questions pertaining use of the [National Hydrography Dataset](http://nhd.usgs.gov/data.html)  I guess maybe we should have an NHD tag.  I think the NHD community is prone to bifurcation enough as it is.  Confluence here might be a good influence.

Comment: I think just `hydro` is suitable here and for the questions posted this far. If someone comes along with a truly hydrographic question the chances are pretty good they'll be steeped enough in the differences between them to qualify their post with something like "this is a real hydro*graphy* question/answer"

Comment: As a Geographer/Hydrologist (as well as an educated Envt'l Geologist), I agree with @Dan, there is a clear delineation between Geography (study of how things vary over space, mostly on/above surface) and Geology (study of subsurface and formational processes).  `hydro` would be a great result from @Kirk's proposed merge.

Answer (score 3):

In soviet/russian geoscience tradition there is a huge difference between these terms.

**Hydrology** is a

- group of sciences studying the processes that take place in the water bodies on the Earth's surface (land hydrology, hydrochemistry, sedimentology, hydrobiology, river channel science, glaciology, estuarine hydrology, soil hydrology); these are meeting each other in a common subject of study (surface waters);

while **Hydrography** is considered as a

- description (e.g. size, order, discharge, flow rate, morphometric or regime characteristics  etc) of the water bodies that are situated *in some region*;
- knowlege and technology domain related to the methods of measurements and researches of the  water bodies;

In brief, **Hydrology** studies the hydrological processes at the "low level" while **Hydrography** descripts the spatiotemporal distribution of the water bodies and its features. However, in the scope of this site there is no urgent need to maintain both tags. From my point of view this is just overkill for the GIS-users.

Comment: Might I suggest adding the description of hydrography to the [`hydrography` tag wiki](http://gis.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/328)?

Comment: @blah238, surely! Should I do it on my own or would you do it yourself?

Comment: Done: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/hydrography/info