# Asking hydrology, geology and geography questions on GIS Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've asked a lot of questions on here about implementing hydrology oriented algorithms in GIS systems.  I feel like I've seen similar questions about implementing geography or geology questions in GIS systems.

Is the GIS stack exchange the appropriate place to post questions?  Answers (and debate over the answers) to the questions cover both the abilities and limitations of different GIS systems, and the algorithms they implement.  It is enlightening in many respects, but sometimes it feels that the questions and related debates should be moved to a different site.

Does anyone else think similarly?

An example, should questions that focus on the routing of surface water across the landscape using different algorithms, and the software implementations of such algorithms, be moved to the [Earth Science (Beta) Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/)?

> [Earth Science Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) is a question and answer site for those
>   interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and
>   environmental sciences.

Answer (score 3):

I'll start with a quote from an [answer by Anna Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169984/215590) to a Meta SE question:

> Moderators can migrate a question anywhere in the network, including
>   public beta sites. Migrating to beta sites isn't something we
>   encourage because beta should be all about a site figuring out its own
>   voice rather than getting questions from elsewhere, but an occasional
>   migration doesn't hurt much.

This means that "moving" questions less than 30 days old to Earth Science SE is possible, but should be carefully considered on a case by case basis.

I think questions that involve using GIS in hydrology, geology, geography, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences are on-topic here.

I also think questions that involve using GIS in geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences are on-topic at Earth Science.

Whether questions on GIS in hydrology, geology and geography are posted on GIS or another Stack Exchange will depend on which community their poster associates the most with and/or believes is the more likely to be able to answer their question.  Questions should not be posted to more than one Stack Exchange site (with [possible exception of Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234497) sites).

Questions on hydrology, geology and geography that are not focussed on [GIS (whether the "S" stands for systems or science)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would be off topic for the GIS Stack Exchange.

If the purpose of your question is to try and promote the Earth Science Stack Exchange perhaps consider placing a Community Ad here like the one for Open Data Stack Exchange which I saw displayed today for the first time and came about via [this answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3892).

---

Some other related Q&As here are:

- [GIS is for GeoGRAPHIC information system. What about information systems for other geosciences?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/gis-is-for-geographic-information-system-what-about-information-systems-for-oth) (similar Q&A to this one - it is also about relationship between GIS and Earth Science Stack Exchanges)
- [Merge Hydrography and Hydrology into Hydro](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/merge-hydrography-and-hydrology-into-hydro) (which I just set to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined))